# Why is my previously successful Chaco build suddenly failing w/ Qt4 vs. Qt5 error?

Tags: qt, conda-build, chaco

A previously (several years ago) successful `conda build ...` of *Chaco* v5.0.0 is now failing with:

> RuntimeError: Importing from qt4 backend after selecting qt5 backend!

What have I broken and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

D'oh! I had the `ETS_TOOLKIT` environment variable set to: "qt5".
Sorry. :(